# Is it possible to group OpenAPI ApiResponse in error status?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi

I want to document my `Spring Boot` Rest APIs with `OpenAPI` and swagger. The problem I have is that I have to add `ApiResponse` annotation for each possible response code and repeat that for every single API:

```
@Operation(summary = "Create new Address")
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "201", description = "New Address created", content = {
                @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = AddressResponse.class))
        }),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Invalid input supplied", content = {
                @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = ErrorResponse.class))
        }),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "401", description = "Unauthorized", content = {
                @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = ErrorResponse.class)),
        }),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "Not Found", content = {
                @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = ErrorResponse.class)),
        }),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "409", description = "Conflict", content = {
                @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = ErrorResponse.class)),
        }),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "422", description = "Unprocessable Entity", content = {
                @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = ErrorResponse.class)),
        }),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "Internal Server Error", content = {
            @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = ErrorResponse.class)),
    }),            
})
```

Is there a way to combine all `ApiResponse`s for "400, 401, 404, 409, 422, 500 and `default`" together? Something like this:

```
@Operation(summary = "Create new Address")
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "201", description = "New Address created", content = {
                @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = AddressResponse.class))
        }),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400,401,404,409,422,500,default", description = "Error Happened", content = {
                @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = ErrorResponse.class))
        }),           
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

short answer, No.
As stated in the [openapi spec](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/latest.html#responses-object) direct children of `responses` object are https statuses for each response. However you can use `tags` for grouping your operations (and not responses)